# Putting a thread to sleep (c pthreads)

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am using `pthreads` and am trying to put a thread to sleep for X seconds.

I have tried `sleep()`, `nanosleep()`, `pthread_cond_timedwait()` (waiting on a fake mutexlock for X seconds), `pthread_yield()`, checking the time every time the thread wakes up, to see if it's its time to run, and finally just busy waiting for X seconds.

The problem is that, although all these methods do work fine considering the result, they do not give the performance results I would expect. Performance is measured in throughput (replies per second) and not in time.

In my configuration I am running 3 software threads over 2 **simulated** physical cores (VirtualBox running Ubuntu Server). I would expect to get better performance when putting 1 of the 3 threads to sleep, as the other 2 threads have one dedicated *physical* core to run on. However, I get the exact opposite behavior (with all my approaches): increasing the sleep time gives worse performance. (Note that the *sleeping* thread's workload is 130-300ms.)

Could it be because of the virtualization (the host machine has 4 cores)? Could it be because the methods I'm using operate in a similar way to my approach using `pthread_yield`?

How are `sleep()` and `nanosleep()` implemented? Do they use signals? Do you think an implementation using a signal handler and `alarm()` would be a better approach? What happens when I call `pthread_cond_wait()`? How is it implemented?

I have also tried using `chrt` to change the scheduling policies, with no luck.

Comment: why dont use a mutex or a semaphore? keeping the thread sleeping only the time it needs

Comment: Can you please give example code, along with actual performance numbers (e.g., from the `time` command), that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: How much work are your threads performing? How long are you sleeping? how often? don't forget about context switching chewing up precious cpu cycles.

Comment: @Jarry and how would i hold the mutex or semaphore for X seconds? Could you give an example of what you have in mind?

Comment: @notfed well you can find the code [here](http://code.google.com/p/lb-bind/source/browse/trunk/bind-9.9.0/bin/named/profiler.c#130). And about the time measurements, the performance is measured as throughput and not time :)

Comment: @DaveRager The 2 threads are always running and performing work, while the sleeping thread should run for 400,000,000-1,000,000,000 ticks and then go to sleep. The idea is that the thread should sleep X seconds wake up run and sleep again for X seconds (and do that forever). Yes i know about context switching overheads and that's why i mention the size of the workload (a `pthread_yield()` takes about 1300 ticks to return in that configuration)

Comment: Sorry but you've never defined what you mean by "performance" and "results" in your question. There's no real answer to "how do I improve performance" until you define the exact quantity you're measuring to determine performance.

Comment: @chetan Performance is measured as replies per second (throughput) by the server (BIND). And by putting the extra thread (which does not handle requests) to sleep i would expect the other two threads two be able to run for more time and handle more requests.

Comment: Something doesn't smell right. I'm going to write a longer passage as an answer since comment space is limited.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @Aaron Digulla that you'll never get an answer to a performance question by hit-and-trial and guesswork. 
  But more than that, I'm not sure you are measuring the right thing, at least going by your claims that longer the sleep between your periodic thread, worse your throughput is. Going by that logic, you could set the sleep period to an infinite number (basically larger than your measurement period) and your throughput should be the worst of the set. Is that the case ?

Please note that measuring server throughput can be a tricky business subject to many pitfalls in measurement and client setup. Here are  some example of how easy it is to be tricked by your synthetic benchmark numbers:  http://www.teamquest.com/pdfs/whitepaper/load-test.pdf

Read that article if you're interested in performance measurements at all. It's pure gold.

Comment: Yes that's the case. Now about the measurement, i am confident about my measuring techniques, although i am not an expert in servers. I will also read your reference to see if there is anything potentially related to my case and I hope to find it as beneficial as you say :).

Comment: Well if that's the case I think you'll have to start reducing your variables. Can you run the same test on a real physical multi-core machine  (so that virtual machine stuff is out of the equation). Also,  another worthwhile thing would to increase the number of worker threads from 2 and see where it takes your throughput.

Comment: Unfortunately running on a physical multi-core is not possible and undesirable. I find playing with the number of threads a really good idea and i don't know why i haven't tried it yet. I will let you know if anything interesting comes up.

Comment: Actually increasing the number of software threads (4-8) did hide the difference (raising the lowest numbers for longer sleeps to the same as no sleep at all). However the application still doesn't benefit at all from the sleeping thread. Also playing with bigger number of threads doesn't help and if you go large enough it starts to give initial picture.

Comment: So without examining the code in detail, I think your sleeping thread was actually doing some useful work contributing to the throughput (other than the periodic, bookkeeping type of work that is). And there are probably some blocking operations (reading from disk/network etc), which means that you'll need more threads than num_cpus to keep the cpus busy.

Comment: Well when the thread goes to sleep there are no pending blocking operations. Also this thread does not contribute at all to the throughput. The other threads are indeed using network and that's probably why it behaves better with more threads than cores. However BIND's documentation does not mention anything related. It requests the number of cores and then creates n+4 software threads.

Answer (score 1):

1. Run your code through a profiler to see where the time is spent. Otherwise, you'll just be guessing and in my experience, these guesses are wrong 90% of the time.
2. `alarm()` could help but it should actually do what `sleep()` does, so I wouldn't really expect a difference.

Here are some ideas what could cause this:

- Cache flushes. If your two work threads use the caches very well, then switching to the new thread could mean a cache flush which can be very expensive. Here, the idea is that the worker threads can fill more cache if the sleeper leaves them alone for longer periods of time.
- The two worker threads need a resource which the sleeper hogs/locks.
- How well did you measure performance? Maybe you measured some other effect (desktop search indexing your computer, whatever)

To get to the bottom of this, you'll have to reduce the code function by function until the desired behavior starts to appear + running it in a profiler to check for the unexpected.